# onBackPress() from navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer activity which has some four fragments all working fine. And I have another activity from was I should call a fragment which is with the navigation drawer activity. I have fixed that one of calling a fragment from another separate activity. The real problem comes here like if I press back from a fragmentB on the navigation drawer activity it goes back to the home fragmentA and again if I press back from fragmentA it shows fragmentB which actually should go out of the app it should not show fragmentB.

I have tried lot of things like: `getActivity().onBackPressed()` and overriding `onBackPressed()` in navigation drawer activity.

Another thing if I add `getActivity().onBackPressed()` its working fine.. the problem.. it affects the fragmentB ,the `onCreateView()` of fragmentB is not getting called and it just showing the view of the fragment and using the previous bundle and not updating.

Here is my code...

For example, keep it as Activity A:

From activity A when I press back from the device and when I press the previous button.. Because i cannot call navigation drawers fragment directly from different activity i am passing an intent to navigation activity and from there am going to the fragment..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Navigation.class);
            intent.putExtra("SELECTEDVALUE", 2);//1 for fragament A use 2 for fragment B
            intent.putExtra("StorePos",position);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Here is my Navigation drawer activity code:

```
try {
        Bundle extras = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState : getIntent().getExtras();
        int selectedValue = extras.getInt("SELECTEDVALUE");
        position = extras.getInt("StorePos");

        if(selectedValue == 2)
        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("StorePosition", position);
            CreateNewOrder createNewOrder = new CreateNewOrder();
            createNewOrder.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction tx2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tx2.replace(R.id.content_frame, createNewOrder);
            tx2.commit();                
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```

`CreateNewOrder()` is my fragment inside navigation activity and here is a code from CreateNewOrder on pressing back button :

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tx.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Dashboard());
                tx.commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: would you able to show some of your java code ?

Comment: Yeah i can add my code.. but it will be very confusing.. because fragment has some and activity if i give it here it will be messed up..

Comment: I have posted my code take a look of it..

Comment: So when your problem appears exactly? If you don't launch ActivityB and you only use the ActivityA (the one managing the NavigationDrawer), do you have this issue?

Comment: CreateNewOrder Fragment --> Fragment B right ? and Dashboard Fragment --> Fragment A ...Show key event listener of Dashboard fragment also. Or you can email me your code on lakshayjuneja81@gmail.com(if there is not problem in sharing)

Comment: If i use only activityA i am getting any prob.. and i have tried keeping key event listener also in dashboard..

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method is just keep a static variable that holds which activity is currently working and then on backpress inside the fragment check this variable and code what should happen on backpress